# Abobe Brackets how to find in a folder

Tags: regex, find, brackets

In the official web:
https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets
Under the title: 'Instant Find in Files' they say:  "You could even make the search in a specific folder"

Can anyone explain how to find in a specific folder?.

I understand that I can exclude folders. But in a big project it is really difficult to write all the files and folders that I need to exclude of the search. Specially if you have to find a lot of things in different places. Is there a better way to find in a folder or in a selected group of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I discovered that in the new version of Brackets (1.4) I can ctrl click to a folder and choose "find in..."

Comment: What version of Brackets solves the issue?  BTW If this resolves your problem you should accept your own answer.